# Scapy won't send packets in 64 bit Windows

Tags: python, scapy, arp

I'm trying a simple code, just sending an ARP packet:

```
from scapy.all import *
p = ARP()
send(p)
```

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
send(p)
File "C:\Python26\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 251, in send
__gen_send(conf.L3socket(*args, **kargs), x, inter=inter, loop=loop,     
count=count,verbose=verbose, realtime=realtime)
File "C:\Python26\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 234, in __gen_send
s.send(p)
File "C:\Python26\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py", line 237, in send
ifs = dnet.eth(iff)
File "dnet.pyx", line 112, in dnet.eth.__init__
OSError: No error
```

My OS is windows 8 64bit. I tried in win7 64bit and got the same problem. I tried in win7 32bit and that works fine.

I can't understand why.. please help..

Comment: Was this run as an Administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have to inform the interface ID, like this:

```
sendp(netpacket, iface='eth1')
```

I had the same trouble as yours, did like I said and got it!